# awk + fit syntax for SUN solaris & linux

Tags: solaris

need help about the following

when I run the following command on linux its run fine

```
  awk -v NAME=MACHINE '$1 == NAME'  /etc/hosts
```

but on SUN Solaris I get the following:

```
 awk -v NAME=MACHINE '$1 == NAME'  /etc/hosts 
 awk: syntax error near line 1
 awk: bailing out near line 1
```

how to fit the following syntax in order to fit also SUN Solaris? or change in order to fit both on linux and SUN Solaris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solaris is well known for the fact that the some commands under /bin /usr/bin are not POSIX compliant. Instead they have additional compliant versions under /usr/xpg4 and similar hierarchies.

Thus, under Solaris you can use just:

```
/usr/xpg4/bin/awk -v NAME=MACHINE '$1 == NAME'  /etc/hosts
```

Under Solaris 10 this works.

Answer (score 0):

the simple way is to use nawk and the rest syntax