# passing parameter from shell script to awk

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I want to split my text file by line count

ex

`GenTextFile.txt`      have   3000 line  I want split to

`GenText_Output_1.txt`      >>  1000 line (line 1 - 1000)

`GenText_Output_2.txt`      >>  1000 line (line 1001 - 2000)

`GenText_Output_3.txt`      >>  1000 line (line 2001 - 3000)

get 3 parameter input from console  are  input name, output name, line count to split

but when I execute, It have a problem

```
/devhome/See/Split_file > ./shell_call_awk.sh GenTextFile.txt GenText_Output  1000
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1
awk: can't open in_name
```

Am I doing something wrong?

### -- Here my code  --

```
#!/bin/ksh

#echo "input name : $1"
#echo "output name : $2"
#echo "line split : $3"

input_name=$1
output_name=$2
line_split=$3

awk -v "in_name=$input_name" -v "out_name=$output_name" -v "line=$line_split"
awk 'NR%line==1{x=++i;}{print > out_name"_"x".txt"}' in_name

exit 1;
```

---

Thanks.

Comment: Any reason you're not just using the `split` command?

Comment: @Barmar

I've used the split command

the result of file name are  -> filenameaa,filenameab,filenameac....
but I want the result name are  -> filename1, filename2, filename3....

I'm a newbie of shellscript and I don't know the way to use the split command then the results are as desired.

Comment: Have you looked at the man page? Doesn't the `--numeric-suffixes` option do what you want?

Comment: can you show an example of command?
I read man page but not found  "--numeric-suffixes" option

I found this pattern.

`split [-linecount | -l linecount]  [-a suffixlength] [  file [name]]`

`split [ -b  n | nk | nm] [-a suffixlength] [ file [name]]`

Comment: Sorry, I assumed you had the GNU version of `split`. which is found on most Linux systems.

Comment: BTW, why is your question tagged `bash` when your script uses `ksh`? There's nothing in the script that's specific to either of them, but why use the tag if you don't mean it?

Comment: I'm so sorry. I just beginning to study shell script, don't know the difference between bash and ksh. Now I have already removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to follow, but the problem persists.

```
awk: syntax error near line 1.
awk: bailing out near line 1.
```

And I was found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624748/awk-fit-syntax-for-sun-solaris-linux)

```
Solaris is well known for the fact that the some commands under /bin /usr/bin are not POSIX compliant. Instead they have additional compliant versions under /usr/xpg4 and similar hierarchies.

Thus, under Solaris you can use just:

/usr/xpg4/bin/awk -v NAME=MACHINE '$1 == NAME'  /etc/hosts 

Under Solaris 10 this works.
```

When I use the command `man awk`, I found that I was running SunOS 5.9.

Then I replace `awk` with `usr/xpg4/bin/awk`

It worked!

@Barmar Thank you very much for the advice about awk command line.

-- This is my code --

```
input_name=$1
output_name=$2
line_split=$3

/usr/xpg4/bin/awk -v "out_name=$output_name" -v "line=$line_split" 'NR%line==1{x=++i;}{print > out_name""x".txt"}' ${input_name}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to do it in just one `awk` command, not two separate commands. And the input file doesn't need to be an awk variable, it's just a command line argument.

```
awk -v "out_name=$output_name" -v "line=$line_split" 'NR%line==1{x=++i;}{print > (out_name"_"x".txt")}' "$input_name"
```

You can also use the `split` command (this requires the version from GNU coreutils):

```
split --numeric-suffixes --lines=$line_split "$input_name" "$output_name"_
```

Comment: Thank you for reply but still error

 

    /devhome/See/Split_file > ./shell_call_awk.sh file2.txt outputxxx 5
     awk: syntax error near line 1
     awk: bailing out near line 1

 If this way doesn't work, is there another way?

Comment: The filename expression after `>` needs to be in parentheses to get the precedence correct.