# Unix AWK field seperator finding sum of one field group by other

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

I am using below `awk` command which is returning me unique value of parameter `$11` and occurrence of it in the file as output separated by commas. But along with that I am looking for sum of parameter `$14`(last value) in the output. Please help me on it.

sample string in file

```
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|05|15|29|46|23169|E582754245|QABD|S|000|351
```

`$14` is last value 351

```
bash-3.2$ grep 'EXSTAT|' abc.log|grep '|S|' |
  awk -F"|" '{ a[$11]++ } END { for (b in a) { print b"," a[b] ; } }'

QDER,3
QCOL,1
QASM,36
QBEND,23
QAST,3
QGLBE,30
QCD,30
TBENO,1
QABD,9
QABE,5
QDCD,5
TESUB,1
QFDE,12
QCPA,3
QADT,80
QLSMR,6

bash-3.2$ grep 'EXSTAT|' abc.log
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|05|15|29|03|23146|E582754222|QGLBE|S|000|424
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|05|15|29|05|23147|E582754223|QCD|S|000|373
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|05|15|29|12|23148|E582754224|QASM|S|000|1592
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|05|15|29|13|23149|E582754225|QADT|S|000|660
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|05|15|29|14|23150|E582754226|QADT|S|000|261
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|05|15|29|14|23151|E582754227|QADT|S|000|250
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|05|15|29|15|23152|E582754228|QADT|S|000|245
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|05|15|29|15|23153|E582754229|QADT|S|000|258
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|05|15|29|17|23154|E582754230|QADT|S|000|261
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|05|15|29|18|23155|E582754231|QADT|S|000|263
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|05|15|29|18|23156|E582754232|QADT|S|000|250
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|05|15|29|19|23157|E582754233|QADT|S|000|270
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|05|15|29|19|23158|E582754234|QADT|S|000|264
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|05|15|29|20|23159|E582754235|QADT|S|000|245
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|05|15|29|20|23160|E582754236|QADT|S|000|241
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|05|15|29|21|23161|E582754237|QADT|S|000|237
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|05|15|29|21|23162|E582754238|QADT|S|000|229
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|05|15|29|22|23163|E582754239|QADT|S|000|234
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|05|15|29|22|23164|E582754240|QADT|S|000|237
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|05|15|29|23|23165|E582754241|QADT|S|000|254
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|05|15|29|23|23166|E582754242|QADT|S|000|402
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|05|15|29|24|23167|E582754243|QADT|S|000|223
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|05|15|29|24|23168|E582754244|QADT|S|000|226
```

Comment: is abc.log your input file? If so it doesnt have any `$11` with value `TESUB` or `QFDE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add another associative array:

```
awk -F"|" '{a[$11]++;c[$11]+=$14}END{for(b in a){print b"," a[b]","c[b]}}'
```

tested below:

```
> cat temp
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|05|15|29|03|23146|E582754222|QGLBE|S|000|424
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|05|15|29|05|23147|E582754223|QCD|S|000|373
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|05|15|29|12|23148|E582754224|QASM|S|000|1592
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|05|15|29|13|23149|E582754225|QADT|S|000|660
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|05|15|29|14|23150|E582754226|QADT|S|000|261
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|05|15|29|14|23151|E582754227|QADT|S|000|250
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|05|15|29|15|23152|E582754228|QADT|S|000|245
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|05|15|29|15|23153|E582754229|QADT|S|000|258
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|05|15|29|17|23154|E582754230|QADT|S|000|261
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|05|15|29|18|23155|E582754231|QADT|S|000|263
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|05|15|29|18|23156|E582754232|QADT|S|000|250
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|05|15|29|19|23157|E582754233|QADT|S|000|270
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|05|15|29|19|23158|E582754234|QADT|S|000|264
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|05|15|29|20|23159|E582754235|QADT|S|000|245
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|05|15|29|20|23160|E582754236|QADT|S|000|241
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|05|15|29|21|23161|E582754237|QADT|S|000|237
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|05|15|29|21|23162|E582754238|QADT|S|000|229
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|05|15|29|22|23163|E582754239|QADT|S|000|234
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|05|15|29|22|23164|E582754240|QADT|S|000|237
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|05|15|29|23|23165|E582754241|QADT|S|000|254
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|05|15|29|23|23166|E582754242|QADT|S|000|402
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|05|15|29|24|23167|E582754243|QADT|S|000|223
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|05|15|29|24|23168|E582754244|QADT|S|000|226
> awk -F"|" '{a[$11]++;c[$11]+=$14}END{for(b in a){print b"," a[b]","c[b]}}' temp
QGLBE,1,424
QADT,20,5510
QASM,1,1592
QCD,1,373
>
```

also check the test [here](http://ideone.com/XSrbHX)

Comment: last field sum is coming as zero. bash-3.2$ grep 'EXSTAT|' bnkbroker.log|awk -F"|" '{a[$11]++;c[$11]+=$14}END{for(b in a){print b"," a[b]","c[b]}}'
QASM,1,0
QGLBE,1,0
QCD,1,0
QABD,2,0
QABE,1,0
QDCD,1,0

Answer (score 0):

You can use a second array.

```
awk -F"|" '/EXSTAT\|/&&/\|S\|/{a[$11]++}/EXSTAT\|/{s[$11]+=$14}\
           END{for(b in a)print b","a[b]","s[b];}' abc.log
```

**Explanation**

`/EXSTAT\|/&&/\|S\|/{a[$11]++}` on lines that contain both `EXSTAT|` and `|S|`, increment `a[$11]`.

`/EXSTAT\|/` on lines containing `EXSTAT|` add `$14` to `s[$11]`

`END{for(b in a)print b","a[b]","s[b];}` print out all keys in array `a`, values of array `a`, and values of array `s`, separated by commas.

Comment: abc.log is a log file with other text content. At the end of each process we are logging one lin ewith EXSTAT. $11 is service type $12 is status 'S' or 'F' and $14 is elapsed time. Basically trying to know how many time service invoked successfully and total elapsed time\Avergae. After grep 'EXSTAT|' only we can apply awk. Please help.

Comment: @Guru Do you need the total time for each service type, or the total time for ***all*** service types? And do you need an average?

Comment: I need average time for each service type. Total time not required.

Comment: Getting below error.bash-3.2$ awk -F"|" '/EXSTAT\|/&&/\|S\|/{a[$11]++}/EXSTAT\|/{s[$11]+=$14}\ END{for(b in a)print b","a[b]","s[b];}' bnkbroker.log
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1
bash-3.2$ uname -a
SunOS utibcouat1 5.10 Generic_150400-13 sun4u sparc SUNW,Sun-Fire-V440
bash-3.2$

Comment: @Guru The problem is that you are escaping a space `\ `, in my example that reverse solidus was escaping a newline, remove that and it should work.

Comment: I tried the command. But getting zero. I am looking for average time.bash-3.2$ awk -F"|" '/EXSTAT\|/&&/\|S\|/{a[$11]++}/EXSTAT\|/{s[$11]+=$14}\
>            END{for(b in a)print b","a[b]","s[b];}' bnkbroker.log
QCOL,6,0
QASM,49,0
QBEND,18,0
QGLBE,28,0
QCD,29,0
QABD,28,0
QABE,10,0
QDCD,4,0
QCCE,23,0
TFT,2,0
QADT,10,0
QCCS,4,0
QLSMR,5,0
bash-3.2$

Comment: @Guru `awk -F"|" '/EXSTAT\|/&&/\|S\|/{a[$11]++;s[$11]+=$14}END{for(b in a)print b","a[b]","s[b]/a[b];}' bnkbroker.log` for average successful time, `awk -F"|" '/EXSTAT\|/&&/\|S\|/{a[$11]++}/EXSTAT\|/{t[$11]++;s[$11]+=$14}END{for(b in a)print b","a[b]","s[b]/t[b];}' bnkbroker.log` for average total time.

Answer (score 0):

You need not use `grep` for searching the file if it contains `EXSTAT` the awk can do that for you as well.

For example:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="|"; OFS=","} $1~EXSTAT && $12~S {sum[$11]+=$14; count[$11]++}END{for (i in sum) print i,count[i],sum[i]}' abc.log
```

for the input file `abc.log` with contents

```
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|05|15|29|03|23146|E582754222|QGLBE|S|000|424
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|05|15|29|05|23147|E582754223|QCD|S|000|373
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|05|15|29|12|23148|E582754224|QASM|S|000|1592
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|05|15|29|13|23149|E582754225|QADT|S|000|660
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|05|15|29|14|23150|E582754226|QADT|S|000|261
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|05|15|29|14|23151|E582754227|QADT|S|000|250
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|05|15|29|15|23152|E582754228|QADT|S|000|245
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|05|15|29|15|23153|E582754229|QADT|S|000|258
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|05|15|29|17|23154|E582754230|QADT|S|000|261
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|05|15|29|18|23155|E582754231|QADT|S|000|263
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|05|15|29|18|23156|E582754232|QADT|S|000|250
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|05|15|29|19|23157|E582754233|QADT|S|000|270
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|05|15|29|19|23158|E582754234|QADT|S|000|264
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|05|15|29|20|23159|E582754235|QADT|S|000|245
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|05|15|29|20|23160|E582754236|QADT|S|000|241
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|05|15|29|21|23161|E582754237|QADT|S|000|237
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|05|15|29|21|23162|E582754238|QADT|S|000|229
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|05|15|29|22|23163|E582754239|QADT|S|000|234
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|05|15|29|22|23164|E582754240|QADT|S|000|237
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|05|15|29|23|23165|E582754241|QADT|S|000|254
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|05|15|29|23|23166|E582754242|QADT|S|000|402
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|05|15|29|24|23167|E582754243|QADT|S|000|223
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|05|15|29|24|23168|E582754244|QADT|S|000|226
```

it will give an output as

```
QASM,1,1592
QGLBE,1,424
QADT,20,5510
QCD,1,373
```

What it does?

- `'BEGIN{FS="|"; OFS=","}` excecuted before the input file is processed. It sets `FS`, input field seperator as `|` and `OFS` output field seperator as `,`
- `$1~EXSTAT && $12~S{sum[$11]+=$14; count[$11]++}` action is for each line

  - `$1~EXSTAT && $12~S` checks if first field is `EXSTAT`  and 12th field is `S`
  - `sum[$11]+=$14`  array `sum` of field `$14` indexed by `$11`
  - `count[$11]++` array count indexed by `$11`
- `END{for (i in sum) print i,count[i],sum[i]}'` excecuted at end of file, prints the content of the arrays

Comment: The first example invocation starts with `grep 'EXSTAT|' abc.log | grep '|S|'`, the second `grep` is, currently, unaddressed in your script.

Comment: abc.log contains other text content as well. grep 'EXSTAT|' abc.log gives all entries on which we have to execute awk to find sum fo 14th field.Please help.

Comment: @Guru `$1~EXSTAT` in the awk script ensures that the script runs only for lines that contain `EXSTAT` rest of the lines are not processed. It is same as using `grep 'EXSTAT'`

Comment: bash-3.2$ awk 'BEGIN{FS="|"; OFS=","} $1~EXSTAT && $12~S {sum[$11]+=$14; count[$11]++}END{for (i in sum) print i,count[i],sum[i]}' bnkbroker.log
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1

Comment: Try thi `awk 'BEGIN{FS="|"; OFS=","}$1~/EXSTAT/ && $12~/S/{sum[$11]+=$14; count[$11]++}END{for (i in sum) print i,count[i],sum[i]}'` . which os are you using

Comment: Using Solaris 5.10. Its goingout of bash mode now. Below command output.bash-3.2$ awk 'BEGIN{FS="|"; OFS=","}$1~/EXSTAT/ && $12~/S/{sum[$11]+=$14; count[$11]++}END{for (i in sum) print i,count[i],sum[i]} bnkbroker.log
>

Comment: bash-3.2$ uname -a
SunOS utibcouat1 5.10 Generic_150400-13 sun4u sparc SUNW,Sun-Fire-V440

Comment: Its because in solaris the `/bin/awk` is not POSIX complaint use /usr/xpg4/bin/awk instead. Read this thread to get more idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624748/awk-fit-syntax-for-sun-solaris-linux

Comment: bash-3.2$ awk 'BEGIN{FS="|"; OFS=","}$1~/EXSTAT/ && $12~/S/{sum[$11]+=$14; count[$11]++}END{for (i in sum) print i,count[i],sum[i]}' bnkbroker.log
awk: record ` [2014-11-05 16:27:2...' too long
 record number 53075
bash-3.2$

Comment: I tried /usr/xpg4/bin/awk for both commands shared by you. Find below error.bash-3.2$ /usr/xpg4/bin/awk 'BEGIN{FS="|"; OFS=","}$1~/EXSTAT/ && $12~/S/{sum[$11]+=$14; count[$11]++}END{for (i in sum) print i,count[i],sum[i]}' bnkbroker.log
/usr/xpg4/bin/awk: line 0 (NR=53911): Record too long (LIMIT: 19999 bytes)
bash-3.2$ /usr/xpg4/bin/awk 'BEGIN{FS="|"; OFS=","} $1~EXSTAT && $12~S {sum[$11]+=$14; count[$11]++}END{for (i in sum) print i,count[i],sum[i]}' bnkbroker.log
/usr/xpg4/bin/awk: line 0 (NR=53911): Record too long (LIMIT: 19999 bytes)
bash-3.2$

Comment: am not sure about that

Answer (score 0):

```perl
#!awk -f
BEGIN {
  FS = "|"
}
$1 == "EXSTAT" && $12 == "S" {
  foo[$11] += $14
}
END {
  for (bar in foo)
    printf "%s,%s\n", bar, foo[bar]
}
```